# Is the preferred method of storing "session" data using Tornado through secure_cookie?

Tags: python, cookies, tornado, web-frameworks

For example, I log in to my server. I want to store things like a username. Would the best way of going about it be:

```
self.set_secure_cookie('username', "foobar70")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just my oppinion. Secure cookies usually does good job to store data secure and works OK, if you need to store small data chunks, but passing lots of data back and forward with bigger cookies is annoying :) So the answer depends of your data volumes.

I usually use this implementation of sessions in Tornado, based on redis https://gist.github.com/1735032

Comment: Ok, yea I saw that but was unsure because it wasn't built in. Thank you, exact kind of answer I was looking for.